# Insert data into std::map <std::string, int> mymap from two different data structure and sending it via socket

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, dictionary

I have declared map:

```
std::map <std::string, int> mymap;
```

I want to insert two values in above map
`*vit` and `hit->first` and then sending and receiving via socket.

My code:

```
for (std::map < int, std::vector < std::string > >::iterator hit = three_highest.begin(); hit != three_highest.end(); ++hit) {

for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator vit = (*hit).second.begin(); vit != (*hit).second.end(); vit++) {
        std::cout << hit->first << ":";
        std::cout << *vit << "\n";
        mymap.insert( std::pair<std::string,int> (*vit,hit->first)); //Is it correct way
       }
    }
```

//Then send via socket

```
if ((bytecount = send(*csock, mymap ,  sizeof(mymap), 0)) == -1) { // I think this is wrong, Can someone correct it?
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
    goto FINISH;
    }
```

And at receiving end how to get those two variables back?

```
std::map <std::string, int> mymap;
if((bytecount = recv(hsock, mymap, sizeof(mymap), 0))== -1){   //Needs help here also

// getting mymap->first, mymap->second.

        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        }
```

Comment: You can't send/receive any complex data structure containing e.g. pointers over the network. A pointer is only valid in the process where you got the pointer, no other process can use that pointer.

Comment: You can't do this.  You'll have to create a protocol and ship the data according to that.  You're not going to be able to say "send this datastructure" and receive it on the other side.. at least not if the D.S. is anything more than a struct with no dynamic memory allocated to it.

Comment: If you think you're going to send a std::map through a socket as written here, think again. you need to send the data *in* the map and rebuild it on the other side.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg jinx

Comment: I wonder if these [1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2470694/catty) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2518644/karimkhan) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1788542/karimkhan-pathan)
are same person, or on same team ? Similar questions being asked since last week.

Comment: @P0W: Same institutes!

Comment: @WhozCraig: I tried as per what information I gather from web. I appriciate if you can give little effort to get me solved.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comment, any kind of data structure containing pointers, file/socket handles and similar, can't be sent over the network, or saved to file. At least not without any kind of [marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) or [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

In your case it can be half simple. The first thing you need to do is send the size of the map, i.e. the number of entries in it. This helps in recreating the map on the receiving side.

Then you can first send all the keys, followed by all the values. Sending the values is simple, just put them in a `std::vector` and use e.g. [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get a pointer to the actual data. Sending the keys is a little more complicated (since they may have different lengths). For the key, you can either make an array of fixed-size arrays big enough to fit all the key strings, and send that. Or you can send each key one by one with the receiving side checking for the string terminator. Or send the strings one by one, with the length of the string first followed by the actual string.

Comment: For simple array or var I can figure out marshalling. But for this sort of example I never come across neither I could found similar example!

Comment: @Catty Then you need to create a byte array big enough to hold all data, and then marshal the mapping into that array, and on the other side you need to un-marshal it. Instead of actually sending like in my answer, you can do the same but put it in the array.

Comment: Could key and string both not be sent togather? Can you please give me implementation for your method. It would be great help!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution can be something as simple as sending a key followed by a NUL then the value followed by a NUL and repeating that until you get to the end and then sending an extra NUL.

But you have to iterate over the map yourself and then reconstruct it yourself as well.

Comment: NUL in reapiting manner?? I want to send it using only one send()

Comment: @Catty since you can never know how much data will be sendable at any time, you can never guarantee that you can send all your data in a single send.

Comment: Even if it's less then ~512B? I think it's TCP packet limit!

Comment: @Catty ever.  You never know how much buffer is around for the send.