# How to duplicate string token to char */char array

Tags: c++

Here I am trying to copy string tocken to char pointer as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "token test string";
    char *word;
    char_separator<char> sep(" ");
    tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(text, sep);
    int i=0;
    for (const auto& t : tokens) {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
        word[i] =(const char *)strdup(t); // Error
        i++;    } }
```

error is : `test.cpp:18:40: error: cannot convert ‘const std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strdup(const char*)`

Comment: *tocken*? Do you mean token?

Comment: That's certainly not your only error. `word[i]` is a `char` and you're trying to assign it a `const char*`. You might [be having an X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: As zneak is pointing out. Are your tokens characters?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what are you trying to achieve ? There appears to be few more error apart from the one posted as of now. And surely there's a XY problem here, as @zneak pointed out.

Comment: My purpose is to get each word of string text in char array word[], each word into word[0] to word[last]. Then I want to pass word into some fucntion as a rgument

Comment: Why? Unless you're working with Posix exec() family, there is no need for arrays of char*. Stick with std::string or boost::string_ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass word directly here:

```
std::ostringstream bfr; 
    word = strtok(& text[0]," ");
        while (word!= NULL) {
                printf("\n Word %s \n",word);
            bfr << word << " ";
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            j++; 
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't put words in a array.

Also, if you people can solve [each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609827/insert-data-into-stdmap-stdstring-int-mymap-from-two-different-data-struc#comment27392693_18609827) other questions, why you need SO users, save some time of others.

Answer (score 1):

Call c_str on the string:

```
word[i] = (const char *)strdup(t.c_str());
```

For reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Comment: thanks, but it gives `error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
`

Comment: This will fix that specific call error, but `word` is a `char*`, so `word[i] = (const char*)...` will still fail. @Catty, you should provide more context to your question. It's always appreciated when people post a code sample, but it's not helping much if we can't be sure what it's supposed to do. Can you clarify your objective? Especially, if you were to do `cout << word` at the end of your function, what would you like the output to be?

Comment: @zneak: My objective is to get each word of string into `char *var`. And then I want to pass this each word to some function which accepts char * argument! By `cout << word` just want to check whether I get separate word or not!

Comment: @Catty, a `char*` can store a single string, but you want to store multiple strings. Do you know in advance how many words will be passed to the function? Will they be passed each as a single argument, or will they be passed in an array/other kind of collection?

Comment: No dont know howmany. They will be passesd as single argument.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
int main()
{
    string text = "token test string";
    char_separator<char> sep(" ");
    tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(text, sep);
    std::vector<std::string> > words;
    for (const auto& t : tokens) {
        cout << t << "." << endl;
        words.push_back(t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*"My purpose is to get each word of string text in char array word[], each word into word[0] to word[last]. Then I want to pass word into some function as a argument "*

You can do something like this:

```
   std::istringstream iss(text);

   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
         std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
         std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string> >(strs));

   char **word = new char*[strs.size()];
   for(size_t i=0;i<strs.size();++i)
   {
       word[i] = new char[strs[i].size()+1];
       strcpy(word[i],strs[i].c_str());
   }     

    /* Clean up*/
    for(size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
    delete [] word[i];
   }
   delete [] word;
```

See **[HERE](http://ideone.com/Ek8Irg)**

Comment: this is cool, but how can I return this? `send(*csock, word , sizeof(word), 0))` or something else?

Comment: @Catty thanks, now for this you should start a new post, and clearly mention your problem, not the [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397) again ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may help!

```
word = strtok(& text[0]," ");
    while (word!= NULL) {
    printf("\n Word %s \n",word);
       //    ch[i] = strdup(word);
        strcpy(ch[i],word);
            excluded_string[j]= strdup(word);
            skp = BoyerMoore_skip(word, strlen(word) );
            if(skp != NULL)
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        bfr << excluded_string[j] << " ";
        result_string = bfr.str();
        j++; 
        }
```