# invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’

Tags: c++

I have already seen similar question but no answer for mine:
In below code I want to store `word` in char array so that I can return array object. PLease tell me where is the problem??

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "token test string";
    char *word;
    char *str;
    int i=0,j=0;
    word = strtok(& text[0], " ");

    while(word!=NULL)
    {
        cout << word << " : " << text.length() << endl;
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        str[j]=word; // Here Error
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `str`. Oh, and don't use `char *` use `std::string`.

Comment: Don't use `strtok` on an `std::string`. One of the major advantages of `std::string` is getting away from things like `strtok`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: But I want to store words in `array`. Will it do it?

Comment: @Cattay `std::vector<std::string>` then.

Comment: @Catty: I've just posted an answer to give an idea of how to to it.

Comment: @Catty why not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18677448/1870232) ?
Same last question of yours :P

Answer (score 4):

Try to keep your life slightly more sane and use C++ as intended. Perhaps something on this order:

```
std::istringstream text("token test string");

// initialize vector of strings from input:
std::vector<std::string> str((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(text),
                              std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

// display each word on a line, followed by its length:
for (auto const & s : str) 
   std::cout << s << " : " << s.length() << "\n";
```

Comment: +1 and I totally dig this answer, but for someone that is finding it hard to grasp an uninitialized pointer, its just a bit over the top. I completely agree its the right way to hit this, but somewhere out there a certain Catty is going W..T...F ... ? (ps: I'd up vote this twice if I could).

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks, but if it would be `char *ar`, then I could have sent  `ar` and `ar size` so that at receiving side I could have fetched array elements. I agree and prefer your way but here how could I send it on socket so that I can receive the elements!

Comment: @Catty you could use `str[i].c_str()` in a loop

Comment: @Catty are you saying your receiving a string with multiple words whitespace-separated over a socket, and want to break it into a word list after receiving it?

Comment: @P0W: thanks. `send(*csock, str , sizeof(str), 0))` will it be correct?

Comment: @Catty nah.. not like that

Answer (score 1):

you affect a pointer to a char to a char as compiler say:

```
 char* word;
```

and str[j] is reference on a char ( operator [] of the string class)

you should write

```
  str[j] = *word;
```

Comment: If j is 2 where do you think str[2] is going to point when str hasn't been initialized?

Comment: @alexbuisson: Thanks, but now `%s` does not printf `str[j]`.

Comment: I only explain the compiler message and don't see a %s in the code... but as the others comments says even if you fixed that compiler error it doesn't mean that your program will work! quite sure it will crash for now!  Note that %s is used mainly to print string (char* or const char*) and not a char !

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "token test string";
char *word = nullptr; // good to initialize all variables
char *str = nullptr;
int i=0,j=0;
word = strtok(& text[0], " ");  // <-- this is not correct(1)

while(word!=NULL)
{
    cout << word << " : " << text.length() << endl;
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    str[j]=word; // Here Error
    j++;
}
```

(1) the strtok() runtime function does not take a std::string as input, it takes a char[] array - in fact it modifies the parameter. Instead to tokenize a std::string you need to use another approach (which is more C++sh):

e.g.

```
istringstream iss(text);
vector<string> tokens;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter<vector<string> >(tokens));
```

now you got all words in the vector "tokens"

alt. declare text as an array

```
char text[] = "token test string";

word = strtok(text, " ");  // <-- this is not correct(1)

while(word!=NULL)
{
  cout << word << " : " << strlen(text) << endl;
  if ( (word = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL )
  {
    str[j++] = strdup(word);  // make a copy allocated on heap
  }
}
```

Comment: please understand. I receive data in form of string that's why i have taken `word = strtok(& text[0], " ");`. Please let me know if there's way with may existing code!

Comment: simplest is to just copy the string to an array e.g. `char* ar = strdup(text.c_str()); word = strtok( ar, " "); ...` just don't forget to `free(ar)` at end since strdup calls malloc.

Answer (score 0):

`str[j]` and `word` aren't the same type

`str[j]` is a char, and `word` is a pointer to `char` or an array of `char`

Answer (score -1):

`str[j]` is a `char`

`word` is a `char*`

try this code... but remember you can store only 10 words in my example... I suggest you to use something more dynamic, like `std::vector<std::string>`, to store your tokens.

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "token test string";
    char *word;
    char *str[10];    // HERE is the change! you can have up to 10 words!
    int i=0,j=0;
    word = strtok(& text[0], " ");

    while (word!=NULL)
    {
        cout << word << " : " << text.length() << endl;
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        str[j]=word; // Here Error
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to make it static!

Comment: that's why I suggested "you to use something more dynamic". The sample I gave was just enough to solve the question you asked: "where is the problem?" and the problem is in the different types!

Comment: This `text.length()` should be `strlen(word)`

Comment: @WagnerPatriota: thanks for the decription. I want exactly what you said. But size of the array is not predecided, it depends on the input. And also I want to keep it dynamic. Is there any way for your solution to not be size specific?

Comment: There's no magic! If the number of words is not predictable or does not have a maximum value you MUST use any dynamics solution. One of the described above... std::vector<> or new char*[X]